# Как по-русски obround?

Tags: одним-словом

Как называется фигура, которая по-английски называется stadium или obround?  Множество точек, расстояние от которых до заданного отрезка не больше R.

Comment: Не уверен, что в русском языке есть подобное название. А слово "стадион" Вам не подходит?

Comment: Прямоугольник с закругленными углами

Comment: Я сам етого слова никогда не встретил. Англичанин.

Comment: @Wilson "не встретил" --> "не встречaл"

Comment: @V.V. - прямоугольник с закруглёнными углами - это другая фигура

Answer (score 4):

This type of mathematical figure is referred to as стадион as best as I can tell. In the study of dynamical billiards the shape is called стадион Бунимовича; and if you do a cursory search of the term, you will find many references where the geometric term стадион is used outside the context of dynamical billiards. Here is one example: http://www.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/g2/english/ssk/0951_p.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Это не авторитетный ответ, но
[*Multitran*](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=3&l1=1&l2=2&s=obround)
предлагает перевод «*obround tube*» как «труба плоскоовального
сечения», и Google выдаёт похожие формы по запросу «плоскоовальный».

Answer (score 0):

Да просто *овал*. Это, конечно, не математически точный термин, но, в отличие от ещё менее определённого английского *oval*, подразумевает именно такую симметричную форму.

Comment: "Множество точек, расстояние от которых до заданного отрезка не больше R,"  —     это не овал. Это прямоугольник с двумя полукругами, "приклеенными"  к противоположным сторонам прямоугольника.  Радиусы полукругов равны  R. Стороны прямоугольника — 2R и L, где L — длина заданного отрезка

Comment: Вот именно эта фигура чаще всего и подразумевается под словом "овал". Вопрос только, насколько формально точным автору требуется быть.

Comment: @Elena а овал это что по-вашему тогда?

Comment: @Anixx Овал (фр. ovale, от лат. ovum — яйцо) ― плоская замкнутая строго выпуклая гладкая кривая; следовательно имеющая с любой прямой не более двух общих точек. Простейшим примером овала является эллипс (в частности, окружность). ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB

Comment: @Elena окей. Значит, это нестрогий овал :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, ***obround*** comes from PIE form ***a̯entbhiu̯ortos***, so the Russian reflex is ***оборот***.